# How can I retrieve single column as two column in sql server with count() function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following table

```
ID          UserID      Email                           Status          Count
1           16          kiran.shahi@example.com         True            2
2           16          aibrahim@sbcglobal.net          False           3
3           16          russotto@icloud.com             False           3
4           16          seurat@optonline.net            False           3
5           16          paley@aol.com                   False           3
6           16          tmaek@aol.com                   False           3
7           16          baveja@verizon.net              False           3
8           16          wonderkid@mac.com               False           3
9           16          mkearl@live.com                 False           3
10          16          solomon@att.net                 False           3
11          16          enintend@gmail.com              False           3
12          16          rbarreira@outlook.com           False           3
13          16          pavel@yahoo.ca                  False           3
NULL        NULL        NULL                            NULL            NULL
```

And following stored procedure

```
    @UserID INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT 
    @UserID AS UserID, 
    COUNT(T1.Status) AS Active, 
    COUNT(T2.Status) AS Inavtive 
    FROM UserStatus T1
    JOIN UserStatus T2
    ON T1.UserID = T2.UserID
    WHERE T1.Status = 1 AND T2.Status = 0 AND T2.UserID = @UserID  
END
```

Which returns

```
    UserID      Active          Inavtive
1   16          12              12
```

How can I achieve result as

```
    UserID      Active          Inavtive
1   16          1               12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to implement case inside `count()` instead of `sum()` function because `sum()` function return null when there is no record where as `count()` returns which is helpful to do calculation in my code. Following code is working fine. In my case `Status` column must be `bit` so that my condition is satisfied and can get the count of `true` and `false` record.

```
@UserID INT
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        SELECT 
            @UserID AS UserID, 
            COUNT(CASE WHEN Status = 1 THEN ID END) AS Active, 
            COUNT(CASE WHEN Status = 0 THEN ID END) AS Inavtive 
        FROM UserStatus 
        WHERE 
        UserID = @UserID 
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `COUNT` try using `SUM`. Like this

```
SELECT 
        @UserID AS UserID, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Active, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Inavtive 
    FROM UserStatus 
    WHERE 
    UserID = @UserID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SUM as below:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status =1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as Active, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status =1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 end) as InActive 
FROM UserStatus 
    WHERE 
    UserID = @UserID
```